# creating a recurring animation that doesn't interrupt previous call

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to creating a recurring animation of vertical rows of circles. Each row begins at the bottom of the browser and goes to the top, occurring at random intervals between 0 and 2 seconds. The problem is that when the animations are too close together in timing, the new one discontinues the previous one, so sometimes the row of circles does not go all the way to the top of the browser. How can I prevent this and instead have multiple rows animating at once?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thoughtsailor/c9j22ybe/)

```
    var timer;

    var newLine1 = function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
        var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            posY = canvas.height;

            timer = setInterval(function() {
                posY -= 20;

                c.fillStyle = "rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.05)";
                c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                c.fillStyle = "white";
                c.beginPath();
                c.arc(posX, posY, 10, 0, twoPi, false);
                c.fill();

            }, 30);
        setTimeout(newLine1, Math.random() * 2000);
    };  
    newLine1();
```

Comment: An old favourite method of mine is just to have an appropriately scoped variable named `working` or `animating` or whatever. This is initialised false, but as soon as the 'job' starts, set it to true, and then set it back to false when done. Then just check that the var is false before actually running the 'worker' function. Simple and readable.

Answer (score 0):

How about like this.  I've only re-worked the `newLine1()` function.  At the end of the line drawing (when posY is < 0), then you trigger the timeout to start another line.

```
var newLine1 = function(){
  var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  posY = canvas.height;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    posY -= 20;

    ... drawing code ...

    if(posY < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setTimeout(newLine1, Math.random() * 2000);
    }
  }, 30);
};
newLine1();
```

It also means you don't need the `clearInterval` at the top, but you clear the timer interval only when the drawing is done (in the `posY<0` case).

UPDATE:
Here is take two.  I've factored out the line rendering stuff into it's own little class. `renderLine` then just manages the line intervals and the restarting a line (with timeout) when the first render is done.  Finally, we just kick off a bunch of lines.

```
window.onload = function() {

  function LineAnimator(canvas, startX, startY) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.interval = null;
    this.reset();
  }

  LineAnimator.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.posX = 0 + this.startX;
    this.posY = 0 + this.startY;
  }

  /** return false when there's no more to draw */
  LineAnimator.prototype.render = function() {
    this.posY -= 20;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(23,23,23,0.1)';
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, 10, 0, twoPi, false);
    this.ctx.fill();
    if (this.posY < 0) {
      return false; /* done rendering */
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  };


  var canvas = document.getElementById("paper"),
  c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  twoPi = Math.PI * 2;

  canvas.width  = 500;
  canvas.height = 700;

  c.fillStyle = "#232323";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.save();

  var renderLine = function() {
    console.log('render line');
    var posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    posY = canvas.height;
    var animator = new LineAnimator(canvas, posX, posY);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      if(!animator.render()) {
        console.log('done rendering');        
        clearInterval(timer);
        setTimeout(renderLine, Math.random() * 2000)
      }
    }, 30);
  };
  var ii = 0, 
      nConcurrentLines = 8;
  for (; ii < nConcurrentLines; ++ii ) {
    renderLine();
  }
};
```

This definitely looks a bit different than what I think you're going for, but I kind of like the effect.  Though, i would take a close look at @MarkE's answer below.  I think his approach is much better.  There are no timeouts or intervals and it's using the `requestAnimationFrame` method which seems much cleaner.

Comment: thanks, this does solve the problem. But what if I want to have new rows of circles entering the screen before the old rows of circles have completely exited? I'd like to have several different rows entering at random times and overlapping each other.

Comment: You could do the `timer = setInterval...` in a loop and just keep track of the separate timers.  I'll try to write something up later tonight.

Comment: That'd be huge of you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a rising image of your vertically fading circles and the preferred animation loop (requestAnimationFrame).

Annotated code and a Demo:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// cache PI*2 because it's used often
var PI2=Math.PI*2;

// variables related to the stream of circles
var radius=10;
var alpha=1.00;
var alphaFade=0.05;

// create an in-memory canvas containing 
// a stream of vertical circles
// with alpha=1.00 at top and alpha=0.00 at bottom
// This canvas is drawImage'd on the on-screen canvas 
// to simulate animating circles
var streamHeight=(1/alphaFade)*radius*2;
var columnCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var columnCtx=columnCanvas.getContext('2d');
columnCanvas.width=radius*2;
columnCanvas.height=streamHeight;
for(var y=radius;y<ch+radius*2;y+=radius*2){
  columnCtx.fillStyle='rgba(255,255,255,'+alpha+')';
  columnCtx.beginPath();
  columnCtx.arc(radius,y,radius,0,PI2);
  columnCtx.closePath();
  columnCtx.fill();
  alpha-=alphaFade;
}

// just testing, remove this
document.body.appendChild(columnCanvas);


// create an array of stream objects
// each stream-object is a column of circles
// at random X and with Y 
// animating from bottom to top of canvas
var streams=[];

// add a new stream
function addStream(){

  // reuse any existing stream that's already
  // scrolled off the top of the canvas
  var reuseStream=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<streams.length;i++){
    if(streams[i].y<-streamHeight){
      reuseStream=i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // create a new stream object with random X
  // and Y is off-the bottom of the canvas
  var newStream={
    x: Math.random()*(cw-radius),
    y: ch+radius+1
  }


  if(reuseStream<0){ 
    // add a new stream to the array if no stream was available
    streams.push(newStream);
  }else{
    // otherwise reuse the stream object at streams[reuseStream]
    streams[reuseStream]=newStream;
  }


}

// move all streams upward if the
// elapsed time is greater than nextMoveTime
var nextMoveTime=0;

// move all streams every 16ms X 3 = 48ms
var moveInterval=16*3;

// add a new stream if the
// elapsed time is greater than nextAddStreamTime
var nextAddStreamTime=0;

// set the background color of the canvas to black
ctx.fillStyle='black';

// start the animation frame
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

// the animation frame
function animate(currentTime){

  // request a new animate loop
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  // add a new stream if the
  // current elapsed time is > nextAddStreamTime
  if(currentTime>nextAddStreamTime){
    nextAddStreamTime+=Math.random()*1000;
    addStream();
  }

  // move all streams upward if the
  // current elapsed time is > nextMoveTime
  if(currentTime>nextMoveTime){
    nextMoveTime+=moveInterval;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    for(var i=0;i<streams.length;i++){
      var s=streams[i];
      if(s.y<-streamHeight){continue;}
      ctx.drawImage(columnCanvas,s.x,s.y);
      s.y-=radius*2;
    }
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=400></canvas>
```